# How to properly design library external access without mess up its internal access?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to design a library, opening only several interfaces to caller, without mess up its own internal access control. What is the proper way to do it?

For example, here is the library:

```
namespace ControlledLib {
    class ThinkTrack1   {
        friend class DeepThought;
        friend class ThinkTrack2;
    private:
        int ResultA()   { return 6; }
        int ResultB()   { return 5; }
    };

    class ThinkTrack2   {
        friend class DeepThought;
    private:
        int ResultC()   { ThinkTrack1 tt1; return tt1.ResultB() + 2; }
    };

    class DeepThought   {
        friend int DeepThoughtAnswers();
    private:
        int Answers()   { 
            ThinkTrack1 tt1;
            ThinkTrack2 tt2;
            return tt1.ResultA() * tt2.ResultC(); 
        }
        int CreateWorld()   {
            return 7;
        }
    };

    int DeepThoughtAnswers()    { DeepThought dt;  return dt.Answers(); }
}
```

, it can be called by

```
#include "ControlledLib.h"

int i = ControlledLib::DeepThoughtAnswers();
```

The actual answer is given by `class DeepThought`'s function `Answers()`, however, to make only one `Answers()` accessible to external callers, I have to make `class DeepThought`'s functions *private*, and invent a global function `DeepThoughtAnswers()` as an entry point, which calls `class DeepThought` to get the answer, then `class DeepThought` has to define `DeepThoughtAnswers()` as a *friend* function.

It just begins. As `class DeepThought` actually calls `class ThinkTrack1` and `class ThinkTrack2`, and `class ThinkTrack2` calls `class ThinkTrack1` and so on... To make all these unaccessible to external caller, all these functions are set to *private*, and I have to define a lot of *friend*ship. Most of all, all these messed up the internal access control!

What would be a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing an interface there are some options you can choose from. The first is to just define a C interface that exports a set of functions. These functions internally call your classes, which are hidden through this layer.

```
<ControlledLib.h>
extern "C" int DeepThoughAnswers();
</ControlledLib.h>
```

In the source file the you have the implementation for this function:

```
<ControlledLib.cpp>
#include "DeepThought.h"
#include "ThinkTrack1.h"
#include "ThinkTrack2.h"

int DeepThoughAnswers()
{
     DeepThought dt;
     return dt.Answers();
}
</ControlledLib.cpp>
```

The files you include in this source then use visibility without `friend` and you only ship the resulting library and the `ControlledLib.h` file.

Another way is to use C++ interface to hide the implementation details. Here comes the interface:

```
<ControlledLib.h>
class ControlledLib
{
public:
    virtual int DeepThoughAnswers() = 0;
};
</ControlledLib.h>
```

Then you have an implementation of this interface, which might look like this:

```
<MyControlledLib.h>
class MyControlledLib : public ControlledLib
{
public:
    virtual int DeepThoughAnswers();
    void someOtherFunction(); //<-- not visible to the 'outside'
};
</MyControlledLib.h>
```

Furthermore you add a factory that allows the client to instantiate your library.

```
<ControlledLib.h>
#include "ControlledLib.h"

class MyControlledLibFactory
{
public:
    static MyControlledLib* create();
};
</MyControlledLib.h>
```

To the client you only ship the factory and the interface, everything else is hidden.
So far, your interface only uses primitive types, which means you do not have to export anyting else. In case you want to use classes in your interface you need to export those for the usage, too.

```
<ControlledLib.h>
class ControlledLib
{
public:
    virtual int DeepThoughAnswers() = 0;
    virtual ComplexAnswer* DeepThoughAnswersAreComplex() = 0; //<-- ComplexAnswer header needs to be supplied too.
};
</ControlledLib.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use more of protected keyword and reduce use of friend keywords and redesign the interface again as its looking messy. A bridge design pattern for the implement and interface will be good and you can hide the implementations as a library and distribute the interface as header files only.

Comment: by " hide the implementations as a library and distribute the interface as header files only", do you mean that i can split it into `ControlledLib.h` and `ControlledLib.cpp`, and only the things exposed in `ControlledLib.h` header file will be accessable to the caller?